# Past perfect help

Tags: grammar

May I ask if I can use "At that point in time I've never had a boyfriend, so he brought some major changes into my life," instead of "I had never had a boyfriend, so he brought some major changes into my life."

I've been using the first option since I could remember and no one ever commented on it and now I'm just confused and sad. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

No. It's distinctly odd with "I've" - that form relates to something with *present* relevance, but here you want something (further in the past) with relevance to the (past) time you mention, so "I had never" is normal.

Answer (score 0):

The first version doesn't make sense, you should say:

> "At that time I never had a boyfriend, so he brought some major
>   changes into my life."

But if you mean to say he was your first boyfriend better is:

> "Up until that time I never had a boyfriend, so he brought some major
>   changes into my life."

In  the second version you don't need to repeat *had* ; *some* is also fairly redundant - better is:

> "I never had a boyfriend, so he brought major changes into my life."

Comment: I think it's more idiomatic to say "I'd never had a boyfriend".

Comment: Yes I don't disagree with that statement, when it comes to spoken English.

Comment: And for written, you'd repeat "had". Your wording seems like it would be OK casually, but not formally.